# How to properly return Optional<> of a method?

Tags: java, option-type

I have read a lot of Java 8 Optional and I do understand the concept, but still get difficulties when trying to implement it myself in my code.

Although I have serached the web for good examples, I didn't found one with good explanation.

I have the next method:

```
public static String getFileMd5(String filePath) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    AutomationLogger.getLog().info("Trying getting MD5 hash from file: " + filePath);
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath));
    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
        AutomationLogger.getLog().error("No such file path: " + filePath, e);
        return null;
    }

    DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(inputStream, md);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

    while (dis.read(buffer) != -1);
    dis.close();
    inputStream.close();

    byte[] output = md.digest();
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, output);
    String hashText = bi.toString(16);
    return hashText;
}
```

This simple method returns the md5 of a file, by passing it the file path.
As you can notice, if the file path doesn't exists (or wrong typed) a **NoSuchFileException** get thrown and the method return **Null**.

Instead of returning null, I want to use Optional, so my method should return `Optional <String>`, right?

1. What is the proper way of doing it right?
2. If the returned String is null - can I use here `orElse()`, or this
   kind of method should be used by the client side?

Comment: Have you actually tried that approach you describe? What makes you think that there is a better way to use `Optional`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the API Documents? [Java Docs Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) Oracle also has some pretty nice use cases and examples at [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Comment: @E_net4 - why not using Optional here? this is a classic example. I want to avoid my method retuning null.

Comment: @Underbalanced - I looked at it. very good indeed, but wasn't helpful my case

Comment: I don’t see, why a method declared to throw `IOException` should return anything on a `NoSuchFileException`, be it `null` or an empty `Optional`. Everyone seeing the method’s signature would expect the `NoSuchFileException` to be relayed to the caller.

Comment: @Holger - what to you mean when saying "be it null or an empty Optional"? this is what I do - I catch the exception, then return null. what would you do different?

Comment: Read the comment again, completely, i.e. the “I don’t see, why …” [you are doing it this way] introduction. *Don’t catch the exception*. It doesn’t make the slightest sense to relay every kind of `IOException` to the caller, except the `NoSuchFileException`. Don’t return `null` and you have no reason to use an `Optional` at all. Then, you also don’t need to document an alternative return value, as there is none. Everyone will understand the contract by just looking at the method signature.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right.

```
public static Optional<String> getFileMd5(String filePath)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {

        return Optional.empty(); // I.o. null

    return Optional.of(nonnullString);
}
```

Usage:

```
getFileMd5(filePath).ifPresent((s) -> { ... });
```

or (less nice as undoing the Optional)

```
String s = getFileMd5(filePath).orElse("" /* null */);
```

Comment: Why the 2nd 'undoing' the optional?
If the optional is return as empty - the client use some default (orElse)

Comment: @Nimrod by undoing I meant that again you have a String, which you need to check whether it can be used as MD5. Having a null then would be even more clear: a fail-fast when not checked - a NullPointerException. But you are right to a degree. Could be useful for storing an optional MD5.

Comment: thanks again and sorry for asking again - at the bottom line - do you think the optional is essential here? The returned null is something manually I throwing in my method, and it's not a classic nullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, that when using a string even if it is not a MD5 - so null or "" for instance. Then it could erroneously be submitted to an MD5 decryption/encryption without check. Then null would give a better failure than "key not valid." - namely "programmer, please catch the NullPointerException".