# Java 8 Optional return type

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I saw below code in some codebase, and I am not sure how we can return Optional for a String return type.

```
    public String generateTemplate() {
         Optional<String> template = Optional.ofNullable(lenderAndTemplateMap.get("LENDER_1"));
         return template.orElse("TEMPLATE_2");
    }
```

Comment: Where do you think you're returning an `Optional`? Why do you think so?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis , I understand that if template is empty , it will return "TEMPLATE_2" , but if it is not empty, will it return template which is Optional.

Comment: What does the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) say?

Comment: Just looked up javadoc. sorry for the question.

Comment: This related question can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811794/how-to-properly-return-optional-of-a-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the line reads as "return `template` [if possible], or else return `"TEMPLATE_2"`", the `Optional` itself is never actually returned. It's just a call to [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-), which returns the *internal* value if it's present, otherwise it returns the value passed in. Both are of type `String`, therefore it's a valid return statement.

As a side note, in your specific example `Optional` isn't really necessary. You can use a simple null check or [`Map.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
return lenderAndTemplateMap.getOrDefault("LENDER_1", "TEMPLATE_2");
```